# What is meant by "the position of equilibrium lies left (or right)"?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I am a high school student currently learning about equilibrium.

I was told that when there are more products of a reaction formed compared to reactants when the reaction reached the equilibrium, the position of equilibrium lies to the right (the product side) and vice-versa if more reactants are formed compared to products.

But I want to know why we say the position of equilibrium is located where there are more quantities of products/reactants? How is the quantity of reactants and products formed related to the position of equilibrium?

I apologize if my question is unclear. But thank you in advance.

Comment: Related, and maybe a duplicate: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/8609

Comment: the equilibrium reaction notation has the left and the right side, why not to use it to describe which of the reactions (forward one from L to R, backward one from R to L) takes upper hand, taking the reaction state to the left or right? // As analogy, imagine collective ball sports with the left and right team like football/soccer, with the "game equilibrium" on the left or right, depending which team has the upper hand in the moment.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not so much about chemistry as about history of science. When you run google ngram on "equilibrium position", you get the following:

[image]

For the German term "Gleichgewichtslage" in the German corpus, you get:

[image]

If you search for the early uses of the term, you get articles concerned with mechanics. Objects can have one or multiple positions of equilibrium, for instance a cube (or a die) can stably sit on each of its 6 faces. This is different from chemical equilibrium, where there usually is a single state of lowest Gibbs energy called the equilibrium state.

If you do an internet search in 2024, you get a mix of physics (i.e. mechanics) and chemistry hits.

There is a mechanical analogy to a chemical equilibrium involved two wells, table-tennis balls and shaking. You can also implement this as a [snowball fight](https://www.teacherspayteachers.com/Product/Chemical-Equilibrium-Snowball-Fight-to-learn-Q-K-productreactant-favored-5207861). In the two-well analogy, you add some balls to either side, and shake the surface. After a while, you will find that more balls are on the right, and that we reach a dynamic equilibrium (i.e. some balls will go from left to right, others from right to left, without changing the numbers much). If you change the intensity of shaking (the temperature), you will get a different result. There might be a video of a physical model of this somewhere, but I only found the corresponding [PhET simulation](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/cheerpj/ideal-gas/latest/ideal-gas.html?simulation=reversible-reactions).

[image]

I think this is the picture folks have in mind when they say "the equilibrium is on the right side". There are several inaccuracies:

1. In the real world, reactants and products occupy a common space, so "position" does not quite capture the situation, "state" might be better.
2. In a chemical equilibrium, there is always some reactant and some product. So it is not all the way on the right or all the way on the left.

Comment: Tangential: interesting to read i) Waage spent time with Bunsen in Heidelberg ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Waage)) hence possibly knew German (perhaps as his brother in law Guldberg, too). ii) They presented the results once 1864 (possibly contributing to the first peak in the second trace), followed by van't Hoff 1877, and a twice by Guldberg and Waage in 1872 ([ref](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_d%27action_de_masse), the French Wikipedia equally has the English translation of the 1864 paper by JChemEduc [here](https://www3.nd.edu/~powers/ame.50531/guldberg.waage.1864.pdf)).

Comment: @Buttonwood I suspect it might not be lost on you that the english translation of "Waage" is scale. That would make the term equilibrium almost eponymous.

Comment: The peak in usage of "equilibrium position" around 1960 is somewhat strange. I wonder why it peaked and what alternative terms might have replaced it. As a side note "Silent Spring" was published in 1962 and a nascent environmental movement might have led to a decrease in enthusiasm for chemistry around that time.